# How do I turn off auto play on an external iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have a video embedded in an iframe in my website. I can't figure out how to turn off auto play. I tried everything: `autoplay="false"`, `autoplay="0"`, `autoplay='false'`, `autoplay='0'` but nothing seems to work. Here's my code:

```html
<iframe width="720" height="405" src="http://www.foxplaybrasil.com.br/feeds/iframes/player.html?vid=120630339756"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use video tag instead of iframe

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay="false" preload="none">
    <source src="http://www.foxplaybrasil.com.br/feeds/iframes/player.html?vid=120630339756" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://cdn.foxplay.com/player/live/foxplayer/js/foxplayer.js?ver=2.219.712.125

Note that the configuration of the player is set to auto play

```css
/***
* Fox Player
*
* events:
*   pdkLoaded
*   ready
*   videoEnded
*
***/
FoxPlayer = {
  defaults: {
        releaseUrl : '',
        releaseUrlD: '',
        progressiveUrl : '',
        lang : 'en',
        logLevel : '',
        previewImage: '',
        autoplay : true,
        skinJson: 'newPlayer.json',
        layoutXml: 'newPlayer.xml',
        seekPercentage: false,
        isMoviecity:false,
        enableDVR:false
      },
```